# Как называется массив и связанный список в python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

В книге "Грокаем алгоритмы" часто упоминается массив и связанный список, но не говорится как они записываются. Хотел бы спросить какая функция за них отвечает, как их можно записать, есть ли они в python 3.x и, если да то, как они записываются там?

Comment: Могли бы привести конкретные цитаты. Не все здесь читали эту книгу.

Comment: Связные списки (Linked List) в стандардтном Python не реализованы - скорее всего потому, что в Python отсутствует классические указатели, без которых, по-моему, невозможно реализовать __полноценные__ связные списки. Можно попробовать реализовать аналог...

Comment: То, что в питоне называют списком (list), это на самом деле массив

Answer (score 0):

*Это наверное многомерные массивы*

Здесь я при помощи numpy перевёл изображение в массив

А потом программно создал массив но изображение не получилось так как задумывал хотя выглядят массивы идентично

```
import sys
import numpy
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Ошибка!', text)
    quit()

sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions


class ShowImage(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.interface()

    def interface(self):
         self.setWindowTitle("Пример рисования изображения")
         self.setGeometry(400, 200, 600, 400)
         array = numpy.asarray(Image.open('pixel_3x3.png'))
         print(type(array))
         print(array)

         self.pixel = numpy.zeros((1, 3, 4)).astype(int)
         self.pixel[0][0][3] = 255
         self.pixel[0][1][3] = 255
         self.pixel[0][2][3] = 255
         print(type(self.pixel))
         print(self.pixel)

         self.image = Image.fromarray(array, 'RGBA')

         self.image_qt = ImageQt(self.image)

         self.pixmap = QPixmap(QImage(self.image_qt))

         label = QLabel(self)
         label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
         label.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
         label.setGeometry(0, 0, 100, 100)
         label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    my_application = ShowImage()
    my_application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: pixel_3x3.png]